# How to disable "note to buyer" in PayPal express checkout?

Tags: php, paypal

I've got a problem integrating PayPal Express Checkout. I want to disable the possibility to add a note to the buyer during the checkout process.

- I'm using the PHP SOAP SDK (`merchant-php-1.1.93_0.zip`).
- service.EndPoint targets to `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/`.
- In the first step of the order, where I make the `SetExpressCheckout..` call I set the following value:

  $SetECReqDetails->AllowNote = 0;

$SetEcReqDetails is the instance of `\SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType`. But the customer is still able the enter a note at the PayPal site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting AllowNote to 0, not "0".

```
var_dump(0 == null) //outputs: boolean true
```

Code in the PayPalAPIInterfaceService, line 2436, has the following:

```
if($this->AllowNote != null) {
    //prop is not a collection
    //prop not complex
    //prop is not value
```

So basically, you are not defining AllowNote.

I have verified that with the SDK you are using, currently offered on x.com for EC, your code does not work, and the following does work:

```
$setECReqDetails->AllowNote = "0";
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! I looked into the SDK code but I missed that they used "!=" instead if "!==". Ugly code...